# Changing the animation or duration of a ViewFlipper transition

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper and sometimes I would like to have it animate between views and sometimes I want it to instantly switch between views.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

I tried changing the animation, in animation, and out animation before the switch but if I do that the current view disappears during the animation.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the exact code in front of me, but I recall that you could specify the displayed child (without animating to it) using

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(childIndex);
```

If you want to change the duration of the animation, you'll have to specify your own `In` and `Out` animation using

```
flipper.setInAnimation(animIn);
flipper.setOutAnimation(animOut);
```

Where, for instance, you have an animation XML `/res/anim/animIn.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

In the example above, the animation moves the next frame in from the right in 500ms.

Comment: What could I do if I needed to change animation properties like duration, when app is running? Thx!

Comment: The parameter you provide into those methods is an animation. You can define those in code or change them at runtime.